# The DIV element of HTML can have name or not?

Tags: html

Please help me to explain about the div element of HTML be able to have attribute name or not?
for example : 
I put attribute name inside it, Than I got warning.
Is it uneccessary to add attribute name?
Thank in advance

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stackoverflow. Please **read** [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute is used with input elements to set the key of the submitted value. If you need to 'name' a div in order to address it from javascript or otherwise uniquely identify it on a page, you can use the id attribute. That said, most modern browsers will handle a name attribute on a div with no issues but it does not conform to HTML standards.

Answer (score 0):

name is an attribute that is used for INPUT type elements. In a DOM a name is unique and you can use to access the element from JS or the backend scripting language.

For example. Lets say you have this form:

```
<form action ='process.php' method='POST'>
Username: <input type="text" name="un" /> <br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, lets say I put as username: Abe and as password: test

In the process.php file I can do:

```
echo $_POST['un'];
echo $_POST['pwd'];
```

And I will echo out the values for both fields.

And this brings an important point.
IDs and Names are not the SAME in HTML, IDs are used to quickly identify and add style to elements in the DOM whereas names are used by the backend script to process the form (PHP, .Net, etc).